# User Interaction Enable in a UIImageView under another UIImage View

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimageview, user-interaction

I have two UIImageView in a UIView in my application. And I need to Zoom, Rotate and Move the UIImageView which is at bottom of the top one, I don't need to do any thing with top one. I've already implemented the code for Move, Rotate and Zoom but the problem is I cant enable the touch to UIImageview in bottom.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You set userInteractionEnabled = YES on the bottom image view, and set it to NO on the top one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIImageView's have userInteractionEnabled set to NO by default. You have to explicitly set this to YES for the image view you want to allow touch events to occur on.